# How to declare a variable type in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I was doing JavaScript, and I was wondering : can we declare a type for our variable ? if yes, how?

Comment: Using JSDoc with Google Closure Compiler counts in?

Answer (score 3):

No javascript variables are not typed.

Comment: This is best for understanding, but not technically correct. It is possible to change the type... or even use this when you declare the variable... but you really shouldn't need to... http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can not defive the type of a Javascript variable
Because it can contain everything from text to number

Answer (score 0):

Technically you don't need to/can't because JavaScript is a loosely written coding language. Though when you declare a variable it is that datatype, only difference is that we can overwrite these values and the datatype is updated.

```
var one = 15; //int
var two = "Hello";//string
var three = false; //boolean
var four = ["hello","world"];//object Array
var five = {prop:"key"}; //object Object
```

Now we can also rewrite these and the datatype will be changed. To check for the data type do

```
console.log(typeof one);
```

Answer (score 0):

see http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp

types in javascript are automatically and when you assign something to a variable for example

```
var myVar = "Hello World";
```

the type of myVar changed automatically to string and you can see it with the **typeof** function